# Open multiple directories without knowing the names of said directories and delete folders within them using a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

Okay, I do not really know how to describe fully what I want and I feel bad for asking something so advanced. I do not know how to do anything other than move folders and delete files and folders using batch.

I am trying to make a batch file to delete certain Steam files and folders which are used to cache data. I could easily make this for myself and call it a day however I would like to share it and have it work for other people also. The problem is one of the cache folders is named with a unique Steam identifier. I will put what I have made so far below.

```
REM Makes a temporary folder.
mkdir %LocalAppData%\Temp\steam_cache

REM Deleted all none essential files in Steam's configuration folder.
move "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\config\config.vdf" %LocalAppData%\Temp\steam_cache
move "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\config\loginusers.vdf" %LocalAppData%\Temp\steam_cache
rmdir "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\config" /s /q
mkdir "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\config"
move %LocalAppData%\Temp\steam_cache\config.vdf "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\config"
move %LocalAppData%\Temp\steam_cache\loginusers.vdf "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\config"

REM Delete all none essential files in Steam's userdata folder.
```

I will put what the file structure goes like below.

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\userdata\256283931
```

As you can see the number at the end is completely random and I do not know how to open that directory without knowing the number first. There are sometimes multiple of these folders with random names if you login with multiple account and I would like the batch file to go into them one by one and delete certain folder inside of them.

I will put below the folders that I would like to delete that are inside of the random numbered folder below.

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\userdata\256283931\ugcmsgcache
```

Sorry if what I am asking it too much if so just ignore this post, thanks.

Comment: [`for /D`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)`%%I in ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\userdata\*") do @echo "%%~I\ugcmsgcache`?

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

`for /d %%i in ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\userdata\*") do rmdir /s /q "%%~i\ugcmsgcache`

Comment: `for /R "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\userdata\" /D %%A in (ugcmsgcache?) do @echo:%%~dpA %%~fA`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`for /D` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html), which enumerates directories:

```cmd
rem // Enumerate all directories under `userdata`:
for /D %%I in ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\userdata\*") do (
    rem // Check if there is really a sub-directory called `ugcmsgcache`:
    if exist "%%~I\ugcmsgcache\" (
        rem // Do something with the full path, like echoing, for instance:
        echo "%%~I\ugcmsgcache"
    )
)
```

---

If you want to ensure that the name of the enumerated directory/-ies name consist(s) of decimal figures only, you could use [`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) and [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), together with a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```cmd
rem // Change into parent directory, because `dir /B` returns plain directory names:
cd /D "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\userdata"
rem // Enumerate all directories under `userdata`, whose names are pure numbers:
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    dir /B /A:D "*" ^| findstr /I /X "[0123456789]*"
') do (
    rem // Do something with the full path, like echoing, for instance:
    echo "%%~fI\ugcmsgcache"
)
```

The [`cd` command](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) could also be replaced by [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html).

The [`~f` modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) ensures that the full path is derived, related to the current working directory.

Note that the [pipe (`|`)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) needs to be [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) here, because it is in the set of the `for /F` loop.